# How to resolve this issue while pushing an items into array?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have a form for pushing an items into array list, but when user choose want to add more devices into array and when change MODEL OF TYPE, the code count it into previous array if material is same.

```
addItem() {
  const found = this.ListOfUsedMaterials.find(item =>
    item.goodId == this.selectedGood.id && item.device == this.deviceTypId);
  if (found) {
    found.quantity += Number(this.item.quantity);
    this.item.quantity = "";
    this.selectedGood = "";
  } else {
    this.ListOfUsedMaterials.push({
      title: this.selectedGood.value,
      quantity: Number(this.item.quantity),
      goodId: this.selectedGood.id,
      unit: this.selectedGood.unit,
      device: this.deviceTypId,
      manufacturer: this.deviceManufacturerId,
      mark: this.deviceMark
    });
    this.onClear(event);
  }
}
```

[form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHz6H.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as the question currently sits, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 this.ListOfUsedMaterials = this.ListOfUsedMaterials.concat({
  title: this.selectedGood.value,
  quantity: Number(this.item.quantity),
  goodId: this.selectedGood.id,
  unit: this.selectedGood.unit,
  device: this.deviceTypId,
  manufacturer: this.deviceManufacturerId,
  mark: this.deviceMark
});
```

Comment: Everything is the same. He count my item.quantity and material if MODEL and UNIT are same or changed, doesn't care... i only need to add items  row by row and to count only if exist same model,unit and device id, if you understand me.